# How do I stop Illustrator filling in areas of a path even when 'no fill' is assigned

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, brush

I'm using a 0.5 3pt round brushstroke and no fill yet Illustrator often fills in areas where there is a loop or corner, as in the example image. How do I stop it from doing this? Fidelity is on 0.5px and smoothing is on 0.
[image: Example]

Comment: Are you using a brush on your stroke? Seems like there's some settings you didn't mention that could have an effect on this. Other than that it sounds like a technical support question which we don't typically answer here.

Comment: No, no brush. Sure, I might need to ask adobe about it. I thought it might be an issue others had had too.

Comment: Did you apply a width profile without noticing? Check the drop down besides the stroke weight. Also, if you take a screenshot of the whole application with that object selected, so we can see the menus and panels, we might be able to notice what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the calligraphic brush settings and the size at which you are drawing.

To fix an existing stroke:

1. Edit the options for the brush used on the path. Lower the brush size in the options dialog. For example, reduce its size from 3 pt to 1 pt.
2. Select the path(s) affected by the size change.
3. Increase the Stroke size until it matches the original visual size. For example, increase from 1 pt to 3 pt.

If a calligraphic brush is not needed on the stroke, you can simply change to the Basic stroke. This removes all calligraphic properties from the stroke.
[image: Original vs Fixed]